# Set Nuget Package Version from Project Info

Tags: build, versioning, myget

My setup is rather simple: MyGet pulls my repo from GitHub on commit and builds. I then manually push the successfully built project to NuGet.

The version is manually set except for the build counter. Is there a way to pull the version from the AssemblyInfo, .csproj file or somewhere else?

I've read the docs and the only thing I can find is using GitVersion and a build file. I'm hoping there's a cleaner/simpler way, e.g. %project_version% :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, a build counter is managed by the build system and can only be reset at best.

To use the version from `AssemblyInfo.cs` as the NuGet package version, you could create a `.nuspec` manifest next to your `.csproj` file (give it the same file name only differing by extension), and use the `$version$` placeholder.

I've got a blog post that explains this in further detail: https://www.xavierdecoster.com/post/2012/04/26/nuget-version-token-explained.html